# Android app xml structing all views according to middle of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to construct my game activity in a way in which all elemnts will be focused in the middle of the screen, when ofcourse the size of screen doesn't change and it has to fit any screen size.

I want all elements to be focused in the middle horizontally, and towards the center of the screen vertically speaking.

I'll give an ilustration of how it should look, I hope it is understood (`2 Players mode`):

(**The indentation should illustrate objects centered horizontally speaking**)

```
                         ***********Player1GameSet-TableLayout**********
                         ***********SeperatorBetweenPlayers-LinearLayout
                         ***********Player2GameSet-TableLayout**********
```

And the second activity I want to perform that in will look like this (`1 Player mode`):

(**The indentation should illustrate objects centered horizontally speaking**)

```
                         ***********GameHead-LinearLayout***************
                         ***MainPlayingObject-ImageView in LinearLayout*
                         ***********PlayerGameSet-TableLayout**********
```

All of this in the middle of the screen vertically and horizontally.

Can I make that happen **through my xml**? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it by setting the this attribute to your root xml layout--

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Now in the following if you keep the width of  `"Two player"` or `"One player"` match_parent then it would align the way you want.